# Xcode Keep NavigationBar Color after Change View Color

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, background-color

I am using show segue to navigate to these two views. `Profile` view is a `UIView`, and `Preferences` view is a `UITableView`. The attributes for both of them are the same.

How can I make the navigation bar stay gray in the `Profile` view as in `Preferences` view?

To change the background color, I am using:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `navigationBar` is translucent by default.
You will need to explicitly disable that to ensure the `navigationBar` is a solid color in order to stop the background color from bleeding into it.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```